# Game of life - 2D array of struct cells, what is the best way to structure?

Tags: c, arrays

In my game of life implementation, I have created a board which is an array of arrays of `struct cell`s:

```
struct cell **board;
```

And my `struct cell` looks like this:

```
struct cell{
    int pop;    //0 if dead, 1 if alive.
    int x;      //x coordinate
    int y;      //y coordinate
};
```

This means that if I would want to change the `pop` field of a cell, I would do it like this:

```
board[x][y].pop = 1;
```

Is there a better way to do this? What is "best practice"?

Comment: Seems a bit redundant to have the x/y coordinates in the structure since they'll be covered by the array indexes.

Comment: `int** board`  should be sufficient. No struct needed

Comment: Oh yeah, true... Didn't think of that. Thanks

Comment: I'll remove the x and y fields but I'll keep the struct with `pop` in it in case I'd want to expand the game functionality.

Comment: This question would be better at https://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: I'd just go for `int *cells = malloc(height * width * numBoards * sizeof(int))` (numBoards because you're going to need a board for the current generation and the next). Then do the arithmetic to go from `x,y` to the relevant address, explicitly. But it's a subjective choice.

Comment: @klutt It's awfully minimalistic for CR, but yes, it could work.

Comment: ... then I'd start considering if I couldn't store 8 cells in a byte. Or 2 generations of 4 cells in a byte...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on what you want your cells to describe.

For example, if you are striving for a memory-efficient implementation, you could use

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <limits.h>

#define  ULONG_BITS  (CHAR_BIT * sizeof (unsigned long))

typedef struct {
    int            rows;
    int            cols;
    size_t         rowstride;
    unsigned long  data[];
} board;

static inline int get_cell(board *b, int row, int col, int alive)
{
    /* Periodic boundaries! */
    if (row < 0)
        row = (b->rows - ((-row) % b->rows)) % b->rows;
    else
        row = row % b->rows;
    if (col < 0)
        col = (b->cols - ((-col) % b->cols)) % b->cols;
    else
        col = col % b->cols;

    {
        const size_t  w = (size_t)col / ULONG_BITS;
        const size_t  b = (size_t)col % ULONG_BITS;

        /* (!!x) == 0 if x == 0,
           (!!x) == 1 if x != 0. */
        return !!(b->word[w + (size_t)row * b->rowstride] & (1ul << b));
    }
}

static inline void set_cell(board *b, int row, int col, int alive)
{
    /* Periodic boundaries! */
    if (row < 0)
        row = (b->rows - ((-row) % b->rows)) % b->rows;
    else
        row = row % b->rows;
    if (col < 0)
        col = (b->cols - ((-col) % b->cols)) % b->cols;
    else
        col = col % b->cols;

    {
        const size_t  w = (size_t)col / ULONG_BITS;
        const size_t  b = (size_t)col % ULONG_BITS;

        if (alive)
            b->word[w + (size_t)row * b->rowstride] |= 1ul << b;
        else
            b->word[w + (size_t)row * b->rowstride] &= ~(1ul << b);
    }
}

static board *new_board(int rows, int cols)
{
    board *b;

    /* rowsize = ceil( (double)cols / ULONG_BITS ) */
    size_t  rowsize = (size_t)cols / ULONG_BITS + !!(cols % ULONG_BITS);
    size_t  words = rowsize * (size_t)rows;
    size_t  bytes = words * sizeof (unsigned long);

    if (rows < 1 || cols < 1)
        return NULL;

    /* Overflow check. */
    if (bytes / words != sizeof (unsigned long) ||
        words / (size_t)rows != rowsize ||
        rowsize * ULONG_BITS <= (size_t)cols)
        return NULL;

    b = malloc(sizeof (board) + bytes);
    if (!b)
        return NULL;

    b->rows = rows;
    b->cols = cols;
    b->rowstride = rowsize;
    memset(b->data, 0, bytes);

    return b;
}
```

It is very common to use `unsigned long` "words" to hold bits, because most current C implementations use `unsigned long` for the largest native (processor register-wide) unsigned integer type.

You can also create an efficient function that calculates the number of alive neighbors. You'll need to handle the cases where the cell itself is the leftmost or rightmost in an unsigned long separately, but in most cases, you only need three word lookups and bit masks, followed by a popcount (or six shifts and eight additions).

Essentially, you'd use two boards, calculating the next generation in the other board every time (ping-pong -like). (You cannot use a single board, because then you'd mix the current and the next generation. You can use a sliding cache of just three rows of data, though.)

However, if you wish to use an unsigned char for each cell, so that the lowest bit shows the current state, with higher bits the previous states (for example, if you wanted to color recently deceased cells in a different color), you could use

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

typedef struct {
    int            rows;
    int            cols;
    size_t         rowstride;
    unsigned char  data[];
} board;

static void generation_shift(board *b)
{
    unsigned char *const q = b->data + b->rows * rowstride;
    unsigned char       *p = b->data;

    while (p < q)
        *(p++) <<= 1;
}

static inline int old_neighbors(board *b, int row, int col)
{
    if (row > 0 && row < b->rows - 1 &&
        col > 0 && col < b->cols - 1) {
        const size_t               r = b->rowstride;
        const unsigned char *const p = b->data + row*b->rowstride + col;
        return ( (p[-r-1] & 2) + (p[-r] & 2) + (p[-r+1] & 2) +
                 (p[-1] & 2)                 + (p[1] & 2) +
                 (p[r-1] & 2)  + (p[r] & 2)  + (p[r+1] & 2) ) >> 1;
    }

    if (row < 0)
        row = (b->rows - ((-row) % b->rows)) % b->rows;
    else
        row = row % b->rows;
    if (col < 0)
        col = (b->cols - ((-col) % b->cols)) % b->cols;
    else
        col = col % b->cols;

    {
        const size_t  prevrow = ((row + b->rows - 1) % b->rows) * b->rowstride;
        const size_t  currrow = row * b->rowstride;
        const size_t  nextrow = ((row + 1) % b->rows) * b->rowstride;
        const size_t  prevcol = (col + b->cols - 1) % b->cols;
        const size_t  currcol = col;
        const size_t  nextcol = (col + 1) % b->cols;
        const unsigned char *const p = b->data;

        return ( (p[prevrow+prevcol] & 2) +
                 (p[prevrow+currcol] & 2) +
                 (p[prevrow+nextcol] & 2) +
                 (p[currrow+prevcol] & 2) +
                 (p[currrow+nextcol] & 2) +
                 (p[nextrow+prevcol] & 2) +
                 (p[nextrow+currcol] & 2) +
                 (p[nextrow+nextcol] & 2) ) >> 1;
    }  
}
```

This has the benefit that each cell actually describes the state for the current generation, and at least seven previous generations (except at the beginning of the simulation).

One interesting option would be to use bitmaps stored in `unsigned long` "words", but on odd generations, use odd bits for the previous generation and even bits for the next generation; and on even generations, vice versa. That way you wouldn't need the generation shift, although you would need to use different functions depending on whether the generation was odd or even.

Comment: A solution that is better than having separate cases for edges is to use a grid that's 2 cells wider in both dimensions and the edges set to zero. Makes the code less complicated and it does not affect memory usage much. At least not for larger grids.

Comment: @klutt: You still need to copy the duplicated bits to the neighboring words. I don't think that code is less complicated.

Comment: @klutt: If you mean that a board with non-cyclic boundaries, with an extra cell that is always zero around the entire board, is easier to use, then I do agree. However, I prefer the cyclic boundaries; as if the board is on the surface of a 3D torus.

Comment: Yes, I was assuming non-cyclic boundaries.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a very compact and simple version. I assume quadratic boards.

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <memory.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int noNeighbours(const int* board, int x, int y, int size)
{
  int n=-board[x+y*size]; // Don't count a cell as it's own neighbour                                              

  for(int i=x-1; i<x+2; i++)
    for(int j=y-1; j<y+2; j++)
      n+=board[i+j*size];

  return n;
}

int next(int *board, int size)
{
  int *newBoard=&board[size*size];

  for(int i=1; i<size-1; i++)
    for(int j=1; j<size-1; j++) {
      int n=noNeighbours(board, i, j, size);

      if(3==n ||          // If a cell, dead or alive, has three living neighbours                                 
         (2==n && 1==board[i+j*size]) ) // If a living cell has two or three neighbours                            
        newBoard[i+j*size]=1;
    }

  memcpy(board, newBoard, size*size*sizeof(int));
}
```

That was all the game logic. Here is the rest of the file to make a complete example:

```
void printBoard(const int *board, int size)
{
  for(int i=0; i<size; i++)
    printf("-");
  printf("\n");

  for(int i=1; i<size-1; i++) {
    printf("|");
    for(int j=1; j<size-1; j++)
      if(board[i+j*size])
        printf("*");
      else
        printf(" ");
    printf("|\n");
  }

  for(int i=0; i<size; i++)
    printf("-");
  printf("\n");
}

int main()
{
  const int size=20;
  int *board=calloc(2*size*size, sizeof(*board));

  // Blinker                                                                                                       
  board[3+5*size]=1;
  board[3+6*size]=1;
  board[3+7*size]=1;

  // Glider                                                                                                        
  board[10+5*size]=1;
  board[10+6*size]=1;
  board[10+7*size]=1;
  board[11+7*size]=1;
  board[12+6*size]=1;

  while(1) {
    printBoard(board, size);
    next(board, size);
    getchar();
  }
  free(board);
}
```

Is this a good design? Well, it depends on how you define "good design". It's very simple, and that's a good thing.